# Angular и перенос текста в textarea

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Пишу приложение на angular, и появилась задача: когда пользователь вводит текст в textarea и нажимает enter, необходимо данную форму отправить, а если ctrl+enter, то сделать перенос.

Проблема в том, что мне необходимо, чтобы перенос работал как стандартный, т.е. чтобы сделать перенос в середине слова, нужно знать координаты курсора (или может это можно сделать как-то по другому?).
Вот какой код у меня есть сейчас:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
if (event.key === "Enter" && (event.ctrlKey === true || event.metaKey === true) && event.shiftKey === false
  && event.altKey === false) {
  let mes = this.chatForm.value.message + '\n';

  console.log(event);
  //console.log(document.caretRangeFromPoint(event.x, event.y));

  this.chatForm.setValue({ message: mes });
} else if (event.key === "Enter" && event.ctrlKey === false && event.shiftKey === false && event.altKey === false) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (this.chatForm.value.message !== '') {
    this.onSubmit(this.chatForm.value);
  }
}
}
```

Я бы мог определить положение курсора и вставить перенос, но у меня кликается клавиатура, а не мышь, поэтому у меня нет координат курсора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> сделать перенос в середине слова, нужно знать координаты курсора

там:
[песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8AuIAerYigLngAkAVAWQBljNUBBOKAUQhAFsQA7VAbgCgf0sOKADoowYA0QdU5AJYBndOxAwAFAHIA1iACewAPYB3duoA08VSAIBpXQCN9sCVM4BKeAF4AfPADePeHgwfXZFPyD9UHMwVBgIWx14AF9PeBAA%20FkAMwt1Bk4VdU8PDwjQd39AwJBhAAc4F1QAERAsqABXCFRVVwzq4UV9WoAFGCGoAHMoVFkQnr7MnNUYuISKhcDg0P1mYQh9CY0ViDSCmHVeqqqs-X1LYTB2mDhOYlgJkFR4KHlv9h1LlUUiAIPIEJUrhFtrt9od1NJCoDAkkMiikr0%20Fl2uwYrN2PAbncBNh6AQSBQqFg6LgmKxpOtNiEwr54GDmLiQgBlEmoczICDtBApUrEoR8QKi%20jCfmC1IAAwAJL4ZTV5BBZGAQKoAAzmNngGZcnmuJJK9QAHRMpuVUAFqvVmtU%20o57G5sF5SFtgr2HAmqAAFia5RlJbgBiCDXi3TAvqVnYbXTz4ABqeAARhD1CE4fZCfywFS8ajSdTGaSQA)

тут пример:

```js
"use strict";
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const { code, ctrlKey } = e;
    if ('Enter' === code || 'NumpadEnter' === code) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (ctrlKey) {
            console.log('ctrl enter');
            foo(e.currentTarget);
        }
        else {
            console.log('enter');
        }
    }
});
function foo(textarea) {
    const { selectionStart, value } = textarea;
    textarea.value = `${value.slice(0, selectionStart)}${'\n'}${value.slice(selectionStart, value.length)}`;
    textarea.selectionStart = selectionStart + 1;
    textarea.selectionEnd = selectionStart + 1;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

---

- `selectionStart` -  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

---

### UPD:

```
if ('Enter' === code || 'NumpadEnter' === code) {}
```

Comment: это конечно круто и тут работает, но у меня currentTarget равен null

Comment: Так заставил всё это работать, только заместо currentTarget начал отдавать просто target

Comment: @Moonwolf45, обновил ответ: `if ('Enter' === code || 'NumpadEnter' === code) {}`